# getting the most 32 significant bits from unsigned long long error

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to store the most significant 32 bits that is stored in unsigned long long into unsigned int.
I can simply use the code below I got from Stack Overflow:

```
uint64_t temp;
uint32_t msw, lsw;
msw = (temp & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
lsw = temp & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF;
```

However, I've used an array to do a similar thing:

```
unsigned long long * bits64 = new unsigned long long[1];
*(bits64 + 0) = 18446744073709551615;
unsigned int * first32 = (*(bits64 + 0) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
```

Why am I getting

> 'Cannot initialize a variable of type 'unsigned int *' with an rvalue
>   of type unsigned long long'

How do I fix this?

Comment: Why are you using pointers in the second case

Comment: On the left hand side you have `unsigned int *` on the right hand side you have `uint32_t` - why do you expect them to be assignment compatible? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Doing & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000 before shifting seems useless. Same for & 0x00000000FFFFFFFF before casting.

Comment: You are trying to initialize a pointer with an integer. I don't see why you are surprised that doesn't work.

Comment: @NetMage the RHS is not `uint32_t`

Comment: The error tells you what's wrong, read it.

Comment: `first32` should be declared as an `unsigned int`, not `unsigned int *`.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Technically true, but for purposes of this discussion, it is *effectively* (or assignment compatible) with `uint32_t`.

Answer (score 1):

In the statement

```
unsigned int * first32 = (*(bits64 + 0) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
```

the LHS is of type `unsigned int*` while the RHS is of type `unsigned long long`. That's what the compiler is complaining about.

You can use:

```
unsigned int first32 = (*(bits64 + 0) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
```

If you must use dynamically allocated memory you can use:

```
unsigned int * first32 = new unsigned int[1];
*first32 = (*(bits64 + 0) & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000) >> 32;
```